# Why HTML page downloaded as file by browser, not browsing instead?

Tags: html, google-chrome, localhost

I used next HTML code as page, but Chrome just downloaded this page as file, not browsed as hypertext instead.

Address used: http://127.0.0.1:5151/

What's wrong with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Greeting</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Greetings!</h3>
    Welcome to the Web Interface.<br/>
    <br/>
    What action are you want to do?<br/>
    <br/>

    1. <a href="/upload_config">Upload config</a><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Headers used `Content-Type: application/xhtml`

Comment: Browsers generally use some kind of HTML header to know what to do with information served to them.

Depending on which server you are using you may have to define headers to serve along with file types, generally dependant upon the files extension.

Just because a file is a has a ".html" extension does not mean that it will be served with "application/xhtml" MIME-type headers.

Comment: The address used is localhost, it seems that is only avalaible on your pc or / and (it depends on the configuration) your LAN

Comment: can you directly double click this file and check whether its working properly in browser.?

Comment: @ShobhitWalia file will be opened in Chrome successfully if extension is exists. But I'm not using extension and filename, user must get some page at his browser if he goes to http://127.0.0.1:5151/

Comment: If this happen its a server issue If using IIS check for the handlers.

Comment: name the file as index.html, it will be opened directly from server url (localhost:5151)

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question.  This depends entirely on the server config.  Make sure that your page is being served with the correct `Content-Type` response header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file extension is .html instead of .hmlt or something else

Comment: It should be the extension Issue.

Comment: There are no any extensions. It's text which returned to user if he goes to http://127.0.0.1:5151/

Comment: Extensions are meaningless.  `Content-Type` response header is all that matters.

Comment: @Brad I specified `Content-Type: application/xhtml` header, but it's not gives any positive result.

Comment: @Broly Show us the full response headers.  And, why are you using XHTML when your document isn't XHTML?  Use `text/html`.

Comment: try checking the html headers

Comment: should be Content-type: 'text/html'

Comment: if not try Content-type: 'text/htm\r\n\r\n'

Comment: @Brad, @ProgramForSA, all right, it's `text/html` and now this works. Thanks you all guys.

Comment: @ProgramForSA Your last suggestion is absolutely crazy..... *if* you got that to work in your server config, you'd break any header after `Content-Type`...